# image slider in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want a jquery image slider where there will be two version of images.One is thumbnail and other one is the big version of the thumbnail. In thumbnail section there will be two controllers for left and right scroll.But my problem is I want that when the images will be scroll by the controller the image which will be in the middle of the scroll that image's big version will come over the page.Can some one help me to give any link where I will get that of slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find anything like that. I would use a slider for the thumbnails and make a function that sets a div with the big picture. This code would depend on the slider or carousel you are using.

Two good sliders I have used are [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) and [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/themes/classic/)

Comment: nope..there is only one type image.But I want two type like thumbnail with its larger version.